# Power BI - sumifs

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to do sumifs in Power BI. I have ID column and want to add up Value and divide by 60 with round up to the second place.

I tried adding sum and filter but not sure how to get the filter working.

```
result = 
CALCULATE(
 SUM('Table1'[Value]),
 'Table1'[ID] = 'Table1'[ID]
)
```

Data:

```
ID  Value   Result
A   1       0.10
A   2       0.10
A   3       0.10
B   3       0.20
B   3       0.20
B   3       0.20
B   3       0.20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the SUM by a condition, then you cannot compare a column to a column. The comparison must be a column to a specific value, like `'Table1'[ID] = "A"`

The measure using just the `SUM('Table1'[Value])` might be all you need.

Use that measure in Power BI visuals. Then use the ID in slicers or in the legend of visuals. You don't need to create a measure for all the possible groupings of a total.